# Visual Studio 2015 Jump List Icons Missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, icons, jump-list

I am not sure how this happened, but I can't find a fix from searching the interwebs. All of a sudden my Jump Lists for VS2015 (other programs work fine) show the generic icon. Has anybody ran across this and know a fix? FWIW I am running Windows 10 Enterprise.

[image: Broken Jump List Icons]

Comment: Do the solutions still exist? Looks like the targets of the shortcuts were deleted.

Comment: Yup! I am actively developing in them right now.

Comment: So, I re-installed VS2015 (with Update 2) from an ISO and the problem still persists! Ahhh!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So I enrolled into the Windows Insider Program and after updating to Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 14366 I got my icons back. So it appears that at some point this was patched by Microsoft.